# Clustering data with equally sized clusters

Tags: clustering, python

I'm looking for an algorithm that can cluster data **as accurately as possible** (no need to be perfect) but with equally sized clusters (+ or - 1 element). I've been reading [this article](http://jmonlong.github.io/Hippocamplus/2018/06/09/cluster-same-size/) where it is said :

> The nearest neighbor approach is the best in my opinion. The cluster size is completely
>   controlled [...]

However, the implementations I've found do no support support this feature (sklearn for example).

**Another constraint :** I am trying to cluster data based on a [distance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_matrix), not a set of points.

I have found [this implementation](https://github.com/letiantian/kmedoids/blob/master/kmedoids.py) of the [k-medoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-medoids) algorithm, which takes a distance matrix as input, but I can't find any implementation that clusters data into equally sized groups.

Any ideas ? Thank you !

Comment: How about taking a look here:  https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-662-44415-3_4

Comment: Do you know any implementation of this algorithm ?

Comment: Have you considered writing code yourself? Take a good implementation of k-medoids, and modify it to force clusters to have the same size...

Comment: That's what I did at the end, but I made my own implementation, it may not be optimal : https://github.com/OmarAflak/kmedoids

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing the original algorithm myself. The code is here for those who might be interested :

https://github.com/OmarAflak/kmedoids

Basically, instead of looping through the data points and assigning them to the nearest medoid, I loop through the medoids and assign the nearest point to it. It may not be effective depending on the use case. In my situation it worked pretty well as I wanted small clusters (2, 3 or 4 data points). Therefore, even if I have 20 points on one side of the map and 10 points on the other side, the algorithm builds small clusters among each "big" cluster. Hope that makes sense to you.